# wildcards in base-package attribute in Spring component scanning

Tags: spring

Can somebody explain what does the ** stand for in context of spring configuration?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.**" />
```

and how does that differ from

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b" />
```

I couldn't find anything about using wildcards/ant style paths in the base-package attribute of the component-scan element.

Could you also point me to any documentation/source code that would explain using
wildcards in the component-scanning attribute? My google-fu is of no use

**EDIT:**
I did some more experiments based on the accepted answer, it all makes sense now knowing how the value of base-package attribute is 'converted' to resource string.

So, I created two Spring managed components

```
a.b.SpringBean2
a.b.c.d.SpringBean1
```

SpringBean1 has SpringBean2 injected using @Autowired

so not only this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b"/>
```

and this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.**"/>
```

work OK in the sense that SpringBean2 can be resolved correctly to be injected in SpringBean1, but these will also work:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.**.**.**"/> <!-- as many .** as you want-->
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b**"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b*"/>
```

This however will fail with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException because of unresolved SpringBean2 type:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.*"/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both mean the same, ultimately a base-package name like `a.b` gets transformed to a resource lookup with this kind of a resource name - `classpath*:/a/b/**/*.class` and your first base-package name will be of this resource type: `classpath*:/a/b/**/**/*.class`, both would end up doing the same thing, getting all class files under a.b package name.

Comment: under a.b and including a.b ?

Comment: Will it also look up files in all the subpackages under the a.b package,like say suppose will it be able to look for a file a.b.c.entity.java ?

Answer (score 6):

A more powerful way of defining what to scan and include/exclude is described in the spring framework reference docs. For example you can do this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Stub.*Repository"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

See section 3.10.3 of [the spring 3.0 ref docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

You can also do:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.*.example"/>
```

Comment: Yip, I looked at that section in the doc, I didn't see any wildcards used on the base-package though, which my question was about.